# Responding to Outlook 2013 emails using Cortana in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, cortana

I just got a new laptop running Windows 10 with [Cortana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cortana_%28software%29).

I've been able to ask Cortana to send emails and dictated them, but I'd really like to be able to voice dictate emails I receive in Outlook 2013 using Cortana or other built-in dictation capability within Windows 10.

Is this possible? If so, how do I activate voice dictation in the compose window of an Outlook 2013 email?